# Numbered gt tables in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, gt

I'd like to [number](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-number.html#) my tables made with the `gt` package in `rmarkdown` rendered pdf.
**What I've tried**
In a markdown doc, defining a function `f` that increments a variable every time it is called:

````
---
title: "."
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
---

```{r}
library(gt)
.i <- 1
f <- function() {.i <<- .i + 1 ; as.character(.i)}
```
```{r numbered_kable}
knitr::kable(head(mtcars,2), caption = "bla")|> kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = "HOLD_position")
```
```{r numbered_but_ugly}
mtcars |> head(2) |> 
  gt() |>
  tab_header(
    glue::glue("{f()} blabla2")
  )
```
````

Which works, but is a bit involved if both figures and tables need to be numbered.
[image]
**Question**
What is the best way to number figures and tables in using the `gt` package?

Comment: Can you use a different function for figures? i.e. `f_fig<- function() {.i <<- .i + 1 ; as.character(.i)}`

Comment: @akrun certainly, and it is what I'm using now, however my issue with this approach is that it requires a bunch of glyphs and setup for every table and figure in md files. I'm wondering if there is a more general approach out there, like `kable` offers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [cross-referencing version](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-set-a-reference-in-rmarkdown-to-a-gt-table/23781) that seems to be working

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/gt", ref="eff3be7384365a44459691e49b9b740420cd0851")
```

-markdown code

````
---
title: "."
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
---

```{r}
library(gt)
library(dplyr)
```

```{r numbered_gt}
mtcars %>% 
 head(2) %>% 
  gt() %>%
  tab_header(title="blabla2",
         label="tab:tab1")
```
````

-output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer didn't work on my computer.
In the '0.9.0.9000' version of the gt package, it is possible to use the following template:

``{r caption-to-latex-ref}

```
mtcars %>% 
 head(2) %>% 
  gt(caption="caption-to-display") %>%
  tab_header(title="mytitle")
```

The table \ @ref(tab:caption-to-latex-ref) is cross-referenced.

I hope I helped despite the lack of a proper format.